# Button внутри ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button

Здравствуйте! Есть кнопка, созданная внутри ListView через Template:

```
                            <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Скачать">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Name="DownloadBtn"
                                            Click="Button_Click"
                                            Content="Скачать" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на нее - производилось выделение всей строки ListView.

В общих чертах программа должна скачивать элемент по ссылке из коллекции, привязаной к ListView, а для этого мне нужно получать SelectedIndex из ListView (или каким-то другим образом?).

На всякий случай, код из ButtonClick:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {                                 
        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFileAsync(
                MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist[
                    MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.OneClickIndex].SongUri,
                        "D:\\" + MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist[
                            MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.OneClickIndex].Artist + " - "
                                + MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.SongsPlaylist[
                                    MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.OneClickIndex].Title + ".mp3");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`DataContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) у `Button` и есть элемент коллекции вроде? `(sender as Button).DataContext`

Comment: Не знал, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос добавлением вот этого участка кода к элементу ListView:

```
<ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
```

И строки:

```
MainViewModel.ModelMainWindow.OneClickIndex = All_playlist.SelectedIndex;
```

в ButtonClick метод.

Comment: Есть же SelectedItem/Index/Path у контроллов-коллекций.